# Why there is no underground/surface temp difference power plant?

Tags: thermodynamics

Not reserved to scarce xxx℃ geothermal sources. E.g. on equator there is around 30 ℃ on the surface and I guess around 0-10 ℃ underground (There are icy caves in my country where in summer there's ~20 ℃ and in the cave it can be subzero).

Update:

Because in chemistry we learned about solubility and diffusion, so what about an osmotic pressure power plant, which turned out that there were some exploiting sea/river gradient. But I was more interested in the fact that solubility increased with temperature and I found that Na2SO4 has an interesting temperature/solubility curve. So that should exert ~70 bar of pressure at 50% solution at 40 ℃. Then I would cool it down to ~0 ℃ so that the solid Na2SO4 dives down and the less dense nearly just water (which gained its potential energy by the osmotic pressure) can be used in a turbine to generate energy and then fall back to the 40℃ container from which the diffusion occurs to the Na2SO4 solution.

It looks that there is the problem with the efficiency because heating the cooled water takes tens times more energy (did I count right?).

A heat pump could be employed which would drain the heat from the solution to cool it down and then reuse the energy.

Comment: Note that the [Carnot efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnot%27s_theorem_(thermodynamics)) for these temperatures is only about 7–10%, and real engines will be even lower than that.  I'd guess that you'd be lucky to get 5% of the heat you're pumping around converted into usable energy.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Interesting. I updated the question with a description of the power plant. I don't know if or how the Carnot efficiency applies to that, or I just don't know if the heat pump in the description would increase the efficiency.

Comment: As I recall, there are geothermal power plants which extract heat from high temperature regions underground in volcanic areas and probably sink it into a convenient river.  I think I heard that Iceland gets most of their energy from such plants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would require a very big plant to get signifigant energy from that small difference.

There would also likely be environmental issues with adding all that heat to a naturally cold area.

At the end of the day I'd say it's prohibitively expensive and dangerous compared to the energy output.  It also may not be sustainable depending on the mechanism that cools the caves.

Comment: That's what I thought, too. The question is regardless the environment and assuming the reservoirs' sustainability, how big will it be and what form will it have? I provided a sample of what I thought about in the updated question.

Comment: I know there is (or was) a power plant in Hawaii which drew heat from warm ocean surface water and used cold deep water as a sink.  They had a problem with pipes being clogged by various growing organisms.